# Popup with "StaysOpen=false" steals LeftMouseButtonDown event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, slider

In my application, when a user attempts to click a slider which is on the main window, while a popup control is open, the popup control steals the mouse down event.
This results in the slider not responding to the mouse down event correctly.
(it seems to get focus and move to an incorrect location)

I found that the that the "OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" in the slider does not fire when popup's "StaysOpen" property is false (and the popup is open),
and does fire when its true (or when the popup is closed).

I was wondering if someone has found a solution for this issue.

I encountered these type of issues in other controls in my application in various contexts, So I would prefer a more general solution rather than just solving this for the slider.

Sample code:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Root"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Height="130" Width="300">
    <Button Width="40" Height="40" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>
    <Popup StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=IsOpen}" Width="100" Height="100"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Placement="Center">
        <Grid Background="Black">
            <TextBlock Text="hello"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
    <Slider Width="200" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Slider>
</Grid>
```

Thanks ahead,
Yotam

Comment: My best guess is that this happens because for the popup to hide when something else is clicked has an event handler for this which does not route the event correctly. But I also have no clue how to fix this http://www.wpftutorial.net/RoutedEvents.html

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `PreviewMouseDown` (and it's derivates) (from the base class `UIElement`) has a default [`RoutingStrategy.Direct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routingstrategy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> **Direct** - The routed event does not route through an element tree, but does support other routed event capabilities such as class handling, EventTrigger or EventSetter.

This is the source code of the event taken from [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Generated/UIElement.cs,90941578b66c90e9).

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent =
    EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
         "PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown",
         RoutingStrategy.Direct,
         typeof(MouseButtonEventHandler),
         _typeofThis);
```

And here is what happens in the [`Popup`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/Popup.cs,40ab7810a8f8c8f6):

```
private void OnPreviewMouseButton(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // We should only react to mouse buttons if we are in an auto close mode (where we have capture)
    if (_cacheValid[(int)CacheBits.CaptureEngaged] && !StaysOpen)
    {
        Debug.Assert( Mouse.Captured == _popupRoot.Value, "_cacheValid[(int)CacheBits.CaptureEngaged] == true but Mouse.Captured != _popupRoot");

        // If we got a mouse press/release and the mouse isn't on the popup (popup root), dismiss.
        // When captured to subtree, source will be the captured element for events outside the popup.
        if (_popupRoot.Value != null && e.OriginalSource == _popupRoot.Value)
        {
            // When we have capture we will get all mouse button up/down messages.
            // We should close if the press was outside.  The MouseButtonEventArgs don't tell whether we get this
            // message because we have capture or if it was legit, so we have to do a hit test.
            if (_popupRoot.Value.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(_popupRoot.Value)) == null)
            {
                // The hit test didn't find any element; that means the click happened outside the popup.
                SetCurrentValueInternal(IsOpenProperty, BooleanBoxes.FalseBox);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it was designed to work this way, and you should likely not use `OnPreviewMouseDown` for whatever you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: First of all thank you for the great explanation.

I realize that the popup needs to catch that event, however I hoped someone would have a technique to overcome the difficulties it creates.
Maybe there is a way to artificially route the event over?

I would be happy to let go using OnPreviewLeftMouseDown, however the "Slider" control, and actually quite a few standard WPF controls listen to it and by consequence get impaired by popups.

I can go ahead and implement my own version of "Slider" and other controls, I just hoped that I could avoid that.

Comment: To my knowledge (and after a quick google search) it's not possible to change the behavior of `RoutedEvents`. But instead of implementing a custom `Slider` I would go for implementing a custom `Popup` as this seems to be the source of your problem and "override" the event/implementation. Maybe you could also try to do a `AttachedEvent`, but this is just guessing as I've only used this for properties until now.

Answer (score 0):

> In my application, when a user attempts to click a slider which is on the main window, while a popup control is open, the popup control steals the mouse down event

While your description is not completely correct, that is the normal behaviour of any `Popup` control. The reason that this occurs is because the `Popup` control has focus and so it is listening out for the `Click` event *even if it occurs outside the bounds of the `Popup`*. Think about this logically now... if it didn't do this, how would it know when to close? You will find the same behaviour from the `Popup` control used in a `ComboBox`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, in my description I tried to emphasize the way which I would like to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to achieve the behavior you require, Set '*IsHitTestVisible = True*'  for the Slider control you are use.

**PS:**
Set IsHitTestVisible = True, only when the Popup is Open - False otherwise.